# Learning based on correlations?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

I am currently interested in a specific supervised learning sub-problem. We have access to Data X and targets y as in traditional statistical / supervised learning. However both X and y are very noisy. Generaly speaking, X seems to be mostly characterized by its correlation matrice. We also have access to (slightly lagged) corelation between X and y. And, if that matters, the prediction is generally evaluated looking at the correlation between the prediction and the true target.

I have some related questions:

1. Is there a standard unsupervised decomposition of X given its correlation matrix ? a supervised one ? (given y ? given correlation with y ?)
2. Given correlation between each feature of X and y, is there a simple/standard predictor for y built from X ? In that regard, does the evaluation (corr) metric matter ?

Comment: Note that (2) is exactly what linear regression does (modulo the lag, which I think might be worth describing in further detail): it corrects the correlation between X and y $\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{y}$ with the intra-X correlation $(\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{X})^{-1}$. For (1), PCA might be a good start.

Comment: Yes PCA was my idea too... as it is the eigenvalue decomposition of X⊤X, it would not  really fall under a new modelling approach. Maybe my question is more about the possibility to modify / denoise the correlation matrix before using it in PCA / linear regression.

Comment: ", it would not really fall under a new modelling approach" I suppose I'm suggesting that a new modeling approach may not be needed :)

Comment: Yes seeing the formulation of linear regression / PCA in terms of correlation make the question a bit irrelevant. Now the question might be more about if there are alternative ways to clean the correlation matrix.